# how to extract flash frames programmatically

Tags: flash

i need to extract frame (can be every number ) from flash swf and convert it to jpg/png/.. programmatically
what is the best way to do that ?   never mind the programming lang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the original .fla files or only the .swf ones?

Anyway, if your using Actionscript 3, then every instance of `DisplayObject` and its subclasses (`Stage`, `Sprite`, `MovieClip`...) can be captured to a Bitmap. To do that, create a `BitmapData` object and use its `draw` method.

It would look like something like this:

```
do {
    bitmapData.draw(someMC);
    //then send the data to some server-side page
    //using getPixel or some other solution
    someMC.nextFrame();
} while (someMC.currentFrame =< someMC.totalFrames)
```

For more info on how to transfer the image to a server-side page check this: http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/print_screen/index.php

If you only have the swf file, you can try to load it inside your own swf and run the above code.

Comment: Thanks , does it support remote swf file loading ? 
that is from remote url ?

Comment: Yes, however, flash has some security restrictions when loading swfs from different domains. You have to check the API for each method and see if they throw a SecurityError.

Comment: Just checked and the draw method does throws a SecurityError, so you have to transfer the remote swfs to the same domain as the one you're running the loader.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [swfextract](http://www.swftools.org/swfextract.html), part of [swftools](http://www.swftools.org/). It's a console app so you can easily drive it from your own software.

Comment: great tools , but i need the option to do it on remote swf file 
i didnt found any way to do that

Comment: If it's remote, then you need to retrieve the swf from this remote location, then process it!

Comment: Note that swfextract doesn't actually render the frames to images. Yes, it can extract existing images from flash, but if you're just extracting vector animations it just extracts as a new flash file.